# Python Check item not in line while iterating through list

Tags: python, iterator, iteration

I am trying to loop through two lists and only want to print an item if it does NOT exist in the previous list. I will be doing this through very large files so do not want to store them in memory like a list or dictionary.  Is there a way I can do this without storing into a list? I've tried the below as a sample but not getting the desired output. Any help is appreciated.

```
list_1 ='''apple
pear
orange
kiwi
strawberry
banana'''

list_2 = '''kiwi
melon
grape
pear'''


for fruit_2 in list_2.splitlines():
    for fruit_1 in list_1.splitlines():
        if fruit_1 not in fruit_2:
            print(fruit_1)
```

Output:

```
apple
pear
orange
strawberry
banana
apple
pear
orange
kiwi
strawberry
banana
apple
pear
orange
kiwi
strawberry
banana
apple
orange
kiwi
strawberry
banana
```

Desired Output (Items not in List 2):

```
apple
orange
strawberry
banana
```

Comment: Are there repeats in your list 1 and do you want to print them? I'm assuming this is only example data, as there are only so many types of fruit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script

```
list_1 = ['apple',
          'pear',
          'orange',
          'kiwi',
          'strawberry',
          'banana']

list_2 = ['kiwi', 
          'melon',
          'grape',
          'pear']

for fruit_1 in list_1:
    # reset iterator for list_2 at this line
    # ........... 

    if all(fruit_1 not in fruit_2 for fruit_2 in list_2):
        print(fruit_1)
```

Output:

```
apple
orange
strawberry
banana
```

Because of the very large file you may need to reset the iterator for `list_2` after/before the `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks. This worked really well and accomplished it fairly quickly with little code. Still new to Python and did not know it can be done this way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MBasith Good to hear. Note that my version uses lists only. For your version you need the file-objects as an iterator. However that is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
with open("list1") as f1,open("list2") as f2:
    for line1 in f1:
        for line2 in f2:
            if line1 not in line2.strip():
                print line1
```

Try to split this file to `list1` and `list2`,and read them line by line.
The above code will read one line at the time to memory, so that means it won't take you too much memory.And it will close the file when done.

Comment: The suggestions about using the readfile object as an iterator are good. But the output is not what he asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` function in string to check, like this:

```
for fruit_1 in list_1.splitlines():
    if list_2.find(fruit_1) == -1:
        print(fruit_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your code isn't working is that the outer loop selects one item at a time from `list_2`. Then the inner loop iterates through every value in `list_1` and compares it against the one item from `list_2`. This causes the inner loop to print all (or all but one if it is in `list_2`) of the fruit in `list_1` each time it executes.

Here's a simple solution:

```
fruit_2_list = list_2.splitlines()
for fruit_1 in list_1.splitlines():
    if fruit_1 not in fruit_2_list:
        print(fruit_1)
```

This uses the `in` operator to check each item in `list_1` against all of the items in `list_2`. It only iterates through `list_1` and will produce the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there's no harm in converting the examples to lists for the sake of demonstration, so I've done that to make it a bit clearer. Of course, you don't have to use lists in your program. This solution uses Python's `for ... else` statement.

```
list_1 = [
    apple,
    pear,
    orange,
    kiwi,
    strawberry,
    banana
    ]

list_2 = [
    kiwi,
    melon,
    grape,
    pear
    ]

for item_1 in list_1:
    for item_2 in list_2:
        if item_1 == item_2:
            break
    else:
        print(item_1)
```